# Dynamically add ListItem to RadiobuttonList with proper ID in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I'm trying to dynamically add radio buttons from code behind. I add it by calling the following code:

```
    private void AddRadioButtonList(string id, bool isBool)
    {
        RadioButtonList radioButtonList = new RadioButtonList();
        radioButtonList.ID = id;
        form1.Controls.Add(radioButtonList);
        if (isBool) { GenerteTrueFalseListItems(radioButtonList); }
        form1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
    }
```

When `isBool` is true, the following function is called:

```
    private void GenerteTrueFalseListItems(RadioButtonList item)
    {
        item.Items.Clear();
        item.Items.Add(new ListItem("True", "true"));
        item.Items.Add(new ListItem("False", "false"));
    }
```

But radio buttons on page are missing correct IDs, and I can select only one radio button from whole page.

[image: radio buttons rendered wrong on page]

I am expecting the IDs of the radio buttons to be either "true" or "false".

What should I do in order to have radio buttons rendered correctly?

Comment: what Ids are you expecting?

Comment: I'm sending string id to addRadioButtonList function, which I want to use later to pull data selected by user. My code worked when I was filling hard-coded <asp:Radiobuttonlist>

Comment: what is the value you are passing when calling the method ?

Comment: string and bool? AddRadioButtonList is called from function "private void AddElement(Xelement element) which takes value of xml attribute and determine wherever to add radio buttons or textbox. String passed to AddRadioButtonList is taken from value of one of the attributes, and value of "isBool" is determined based on swich. Currently isBool can be only true.

Comment: The only thing I see are correct ID's (`false_0`, `false_1`).

Comment: How are they correct? Where in code am I setting them? IDs of radio buttons should be either "true" or "false"

Comment: Ids must be unique. Having elements with duplicate ids will break things like `document.getElementById("false")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` of the `input` element will be `true` or `false` but the ID is automatically generated by ASP.NET based on the ID you give the RadioButtonList (not the ListItem) and then an underscore and then a  sequential number for each RadioButtonList option. (Will vary based on `ClientIDMode` setting).

So if you assign an ID of `test` to a RadioButtonList then the `input` elements that ASP.NET generates for each `ListItem` will have the ID `test_1`, `test_2`, `test_3`, etc etc.

If you were to change to RadioButtons instead of a RadioButtonList then each RadioButton would have the ID you specify (depending on `ClientIDMode`).